# Editing complex arrays for export to Python

Tags: import, replacement, complex, python, csv-format

Quick question, can anyone advise on an efficient way to convert complex arrays with complex part denoted '${I}$' in Mathematica to '$j$' (as used in Python) and curly brackets '{}' replaced with '[]' (as used in Python). I intend to then export the array as a csv. file and subsequently import it from Python.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Convert the data to  "String" and then use StringReplace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably better than going through CSV is to use `"PythonExpression"` as an exporting format, *e.g.*

```
ExportString[{1+2I,3+4I},"PythonExpression"]
(*"[Complex(1,2), Complex(3,4)]"*)
```

**EDIT:** Python seems to expect complex numbers defined through `complex(real,imag)` and not `Complex(real,imag)`, so the full workflow would be:

- In Mathematica

```
Export["data.txt",{1+2I,3+4I},"PythonExpression"]
```

- In Python

```python
with open("data.txt","r") as datafile:
    data = eval(datafile.read().lower())
```

I haven't really tested the efficiency of this approach, but unless that's a concern this technique seems rather convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you aren't using CSV, how do you access the array through Python? Is a special Python configuration required?

Comment: I'd expect `eval` to work on the python side, so no special configuration required... but somehow Mathematica is exporting "Complex(real,imag)" when Python expects "complex(real,imag)"... so I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Seems to work well on my side. Thanks, much appreciated.